# how do i write nested map code in swift

Tags: swift3

useyourloaf.com/blog/swift-guide-to-map-filter-reduce/

I am using this site to learn how swift maps work as well as looking at code from various frameworks. (i learn better by doing)

Right now, i am looking at the framework for [`Log`](https://github.com/delba/Log/blob/master/Source/Benchmarker.swift)

```
let durations = (0..<n).map { _ in duration { block() } }
----------------------------------------------------------
private func duration(_ block: () -> Void) -> Double {
    let date = Date()

    block()

    return abs(date.timeIntervalSinceNow)
}
```

that code can be found here https://github.com/delba/Log/blob/master/Source/Benchmarker.swift#L44.

my question is, is it possible to rewrite without the use of a function?
what i have below gives me an error on the

```
    let durations2 = (0..<n).map ({
        (block: (block) -> Void) -> Double in // the second block throws an error 'use of undeclared type block'
        let date = Date()
        block()
        return abs(date.timeIntervalSinceNow)
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `map`, the argument to the closure will be of the type of the "stuff" you are using `map` on. `0..<n` is a `CountableRange<Int>` containing 0, 1, ..., n-1 so the argument will be of type `Int`. You want to create an array of time intervals. Maybe with explicit types this will become clearer:

```
let range: CountableRange<Int> = 0..<n
let durations2 = range.map { (Int) -> TimeInterval in
    let date = Date()
    // Code you want to measure.
    return abs(date.timeIntervalSinceNow)
}
```

With `map`, you are usually taking a list of elements and create another list of elements by applying a closure on each of those input elements. In your example, you are ignoring the input elements 0, 1, ..., n-1 and are only interested in the generated time interval output elements. Somewhat equivalent code not using map would be

```
var durations3: [TimeInterval] = []
for _ in 0..<n {
    let date = Date()
    // Code you want to measure.
    durations3.append(abs(date.timeIntervalSinceNow))
}
```

Comment: been a while since i tinkered with swift so, sorry for the late response but this did help me understand a bit better. Thanks